# Anaconda Navigator / apps won't launch / Windows 7

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, windows-7-x64

Anaconda3 installed easily on Win-7/x64

- Installed in `d:\Anaconda3` directory to avoid issue with *space* in my user name (User Name = `\users\first last\`)
- Path **not** set for python, as advised during installation

All apps / python work from the command line.  However,

1. Installation link in Windows Start Menu **still** points to my home directory (with a space in the name)
2. Apps will **not** launch from the Anaconda Navigator (progress bar moves and nothing happens... including no error message)
3. Apps will launch from Anaconda Prompt

Troubleshooting:

- Pointed the *Anaconda Navigator Properties* to *Start In* 'D:\Home'
- Ran `conda update anaconda`

Answer (score 0):

Try with the followings as mentioned in this [link](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/8373):

```
conda update conda
conda update anaconda-navigator
conda update navigator-updater
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the following after researching (and tearing my hair out) for a day. From Command Prompt, I entered the following after navigating to the `C:\Users\<user>\Anaconda3\Scripts` directory:

```
activate root
```

That turns it into an Anaconda prompt.

Then, like others here, I updated Anaconda all the way around:

```
conda update -n root conda
conda update --all
conda update conda
conda update anaconda-navigator
```

I also did a reset:

```
anaconda-navigator --reset
```

I guess, after a while, one gets desperate (this followed three uninstalls/reinstalls etc.) Still, I got this error, which had started the entire "journey":

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "windows" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

Otherwise, Anaconda did not show up on the Start menu, and could not be launched. PyQt5 was installed.

What also did not do anything was adding Anaconda's path to PATH in system variables.

The last thing I did fixed everything: I copied the entire PyQt5 folder from

```
C:\Users\<user>\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\
```

where it seemed more complete/contain more to

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\
```

and then tried it again. And it finally came up.

Hope this helps somebody.